# jQuery filter() for country/state/city list with already loaded data (no ajax calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, drop-down-menu

I am creating a form with three dropdowns, country, state and city.

On select of a country, filtered state dropdown should appear and based on state selection respective cities.

I am working in a scenario where **I can't make any ajax calls** as all country, state, city lists are loaded in DOM with backend API call.
So, when the page loads all country/state/city list are loaded.

**What I have tried:**
I have used jquery filter to filter thorough select value on jquery change event.

```
$(".country").on('change', function(event){
...
$('.state').html($('.state').find('option').filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
...
}
```

Similarly I have written a method for state dropdown change to filter city

HTML:

```
<select name="country" id="country" class="country">  
 <option value="US">USA</option>
 <option value="AU">Australia</option>
 ...
</select>
```

**Issue:**
This works perfectly first time. But next time when I try to change the country again (to USA to Australia) the method is searching 
in filtered USA' states not all state lists, which were loaded when page loaded for first time. So dropdown is coming as blank.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $('.state').html(.....) is removing rest of the options for good hence you don't get them again. You should have all the states and cities in an array so you can use it to first fill all, then filter. Or even better first filter the array (not the dom) and then generate select.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.state').html($('.state').find('option').filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
```

is overriding your state list, so you lost the list of states present initially..
There are multiple ways of solving this.

1. You can keep list of states in javascript variable and you this to filter out based on this variable

   `var countryLookup = { "USA": [ {key: "State Display Name", value: "state_value", ...], "AU": [ {key: "State Display Name", value: "state_value" }, ];`

   ```
   // on change handler for country dropdown    
   function onCountryChange(country) {
       var $option = $('<option class='state-item'/>');
       var $stateSelect = $('.state');
       var stateList = countryLookup[country];
       $stateSelect.html('');
       $.each(stateList, function(indx, state) {
         $option.clone().val(state.value).text(state.key).appendTo($stateSelect);
       });
   }
   ```
2. You can keep an hidden list/dropdown and clone and apply filter on that and update the html. Clone api for reference -> https://api.jquery.com/clone/
3. Other option is you can keep list in javascript variable and use somekind of template engine -> https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl